# LuaJIT cannot load libtorch.dll

Tags: lua, torch, luajit, luarocks, libtorch

Following the guide [here](https://github.com/torch/torch7/wiki/Windows#using-visual-studio-manually) as best I could (C drive not X, 64 bit), I have reached the stage of testing Torch with

```
require('torch')
torch.test()
```

Upon trying to require the torch module I am given this error:

```
C:\torch\install\lua\torch\init.lua:13: cannot load 'C:\torch\install\libtorch.dll'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        C:\torch\install\lua\torch\init.lua:13: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: at 0x003c19a0
```

[image: torch/lua install folder]

libtorch.dll does exist exactly where lua says it is, and the error message doesn't give any reason why it can't load it. I have redone the whole procedure a couple of times now, same result. Googled for similar issues, didn't find any that matched my problem. At a complete loss on what to do.

If I use `luarocks install torch`, I am able to require it, but then it doesn't recognize my lapack libs and gives me errors about it during `torch.test()`. According to the previously linked tutorial I am following, I am supposed to solve this by downloading the torch rockspec file, manually setting the path to my lapack libs, then installing the altered rockspec file, but doing so results in this problem I am writing about.

All I want to do is make [spaghetti images](https://github.com/jcjohnson/neural-style) but I cannot get torch to work. I apologize for the vagueness.

Comment: Are host exe and libtorch.dll both 64-bit?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Yeah, both are x64